# Exporting netcdf file in MODIS sinusoidal grid with xarray

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I have 18 tif files in the MODIS sinusoidal grid I would like to convert to one file in netcdf format.  I have converted the tifs to an xarray `xarray.core.dataset.Dataset` format called `stacked`.  At this point if my projection is WGS 84 I can usually export to netcdf like so:

```
stacked.lat.attrs['long_name'] = 'latitude'
stacked.lat.attrs['units'] = 'degrees_north'
stacked.lat.attrs['standard_name'] = 'latitude'
   
stacked.long.attrs['long_name'] = 'longitude'
stacked.long.attrs['units'] = 'degrees_east'
stacked.long.attrs['standard_name'] = 'longitude'
   
    
stacked[variable].attrs['coordinates'] = 'time lat long'
```

but since MODIS is not in degrees this causes a problem.  I tried to change the units to `'meters'` but that did not work.  Is there a way to export to netcdf with MODIS (https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/modis-sinusoidal-3/) instead of WGS 84?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/modis-sinusoidal-3/, I am able to define `crs` using the proj4 standard. Then, I use `rioxarray` to georeference the dataset. Assuming your dimensions-coordinates are `y` and `x`, I would write :

```
import rioxarray

crs = "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

stacked = stacked.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="x", y_dim="y").rio.write_grid_mapping().rio.write_crs(crs).rio.write_coordinate_system()
```

A `spatial_ref` coordinate is created, and the units of your coordinates are normally correct now.

Tell me if it doesn't fit exactly your question.